# Insert a formatted footnote using Microsoft.Interop.Office.Word

Tags: c#, winforms, office-interop

I am trying to inset ***formatted*** footnotes into an open word document using a WinForms application.

While I am able to use Interop.Word to set plain text footnotes and so long as I use plain text it works fine.  However, I also want the user to be able to paste rich text formatted text from a rich text box into the footnote.  This never works and always shows the rich text codes.

I know that footnotes can take formatting because if I put the rich text int a clipboard and paste it into a footnote the formatting is preserved.

I have even tried putting the rich text into the clipboard and then setting the string (s) to the clipboard contents using "s = Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Rtf);"  It seems as if this should be exactly what I am pasting, but if I paste into the footnote it works.  If the program sets it using the code below it does not work.

I appreciate any help.

```
application = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Word.Application");

application.ActiveDocument.Footnotes.Add(application.Selection.Range, "", s);
```

Comment: In the code you show, `s` is a `string`. A `string` cannot contain formatting information - it's just a series of characters. The only kind of `string` information that can inserted formatted content to a Word document must be valid Word Open XML in the OPC flat file format. For RichText Word requires a converter, meaning the code must use `InsertFile` or paste from the Clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

Cindy's answer was helpful.  I fixed the problem by doing the following:

1. Saving the current selected position in the document and current clipboard contents.
2. Inserting a blank footnote.
3. Selecting the footnote.
4. Putting the string into the clipboard as rich text format.
5. Sending/pasting the information from the clipboard to Word.
6. Restoring the clipboard and original selected position in the document.